# R Shiny : Save previous reactive value while using reactiveTimer

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here is a toy example in which I draw a number between 1 and 10 every second, and where I would like to display those numbers only if the difference between the actual number which has just get drawn and the previous drawn number equals 1. So if the sequence of drawn numbers is : [5,7,8,2,3]. I want to display successively [8,3]. I guess it's all about reactive values and isolate function but I could not realize what I wanted. My failed attempts in commentaries.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("time"),
    textOutput("num")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)
  timestamp<-reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    Sys.time()
  })

  random_num<-reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    sample(x=seq(1,10),size = 1,replace = FALSE,pro)
  })

# My attempt : obviously do not work
#   values <- reactiveValues(old=1)
#   observe({
#     if (random_num()==values$old) {values$display=random_num()}
#     else {values$old=random_num()}
#   })  

  output$time <- renderText({paste("time :",timestamp())})
  output$num <- renderText({paste("num :",random_num())})
  #My attempt : obviously do not work
  # output$num <- renderText({paste("num :",isolate(values$display))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311778/how-to-remember-information-from-the-previous-iteration-when-using-reactivetim) which looks like to mine, but it's quite different.

Comment: You may use a `reactiveValues` object. It is essentilly a list that you can update whenever your condition is mer, then use the `reactiveValues` objecthe in your `output $num`

Comment: Yeah, but actually I tried to do what you recommended as you can see in the commentaries of the code, but I failed. I might miss something.

Comment: Just like in your linked question, you can use either a global variable or a `reactiveValues` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
library(shiny)

old <- NULL

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("time"),
    textOutput("num"),
    textOutput("num_raw")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)

  timestamp<-reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    Sys.time()
  })

  random_num<-reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    r <- sample(x=seq(1,10),size = 1,replace = FALSE)
  })

  observe({
    output$time <- renderText({paste("time :",timestamp())})
    r <- random_num()
    if (!is.null(old) && r - old == 1) {
      output$num <- renderText({paste("num :",r)})
    }
    output$num_raw <- renderText({paste("raw num : ", r)})
    old <<- r
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Awesome! Well it seems I did not well understand the the answer to the linked question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is still a little thing that I do not get. Why the hell this '<<-' instead of '<-' ??

Comment: It is used to assign values to global variables. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html